# AWS Api gateway {proxy+} throws internal server error when 2 parent paths are added

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have a working lambda listening to HTTP API gateway with path  **/medication/{proxy+}**. This workflow is working fine and is responding with expected result when **{baseurl}/{basepath}/medication/{proxy+}** is invoked. But in order to version the APIs, I decided to add a root path to this => **/v1/medication/{proxy+}**.
But on invoking **{baseurl}/{basepath}/v1/medication/{proxy+}** I am getting internal server error, with the same code(lambda) which was used before.

I have deployed both lambda and API gateway using sam/cloudformation template.

Below is the stripped-down template and swagger definitions:

swagger.yml

```
v1/medication/{proxy+}:
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
      tags:
      - "health"
      summary: "Get medication details."
      description: "Endpoint for fetching medication details"
      operationId: "get allergy"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: 'arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:{AWS:Region}:function:ucm-dfd-dev-DFDNotification/invocations'
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws_proxy"
      security:
        - dfd_authorizer: []
```

template.yml

```
DFDAllergy:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-DFDAllergy'
      Handler: controllers/allergy.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      CodeUri: src
      Layers:
        - !Ref DFDPackageLayer
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::{AWS:Region}:role/Lambda_Access_Role-Dev'
      Events:
        samapinew:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref DFDApi
            Path: /v1/medication/{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
```

Here the path in template.yml and endpoint in swagger.yml are only changes made to incorporate **v1** as root path.
Cant seem to find out what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked cloudwatch logs for any error messages?

Comment: yes, only anomaly that i could find was getting undefined in place of hexcode for whatever code is written in execution context and outside handler method. On further inspection a simple lambda which returns a sample response without application logic is working fine with v1/medication/{proxy+}. So is there any restriction for writing application logic outside handler when using proxy?